# Online / offline sync with AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flash-builder, flex4.5

I am working in flex 4.6 air application, in which i am fetching data from server through HTTP services. We are using the Mysql database and php for making services. I want to implement the online/offline functionality in this application any one has any idea about that how it is possible through HTTP services or there is any other coding stuff for achieving it.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean with "the online/offline functionality".

Comment: If internet is not connected then the application should be work without internet that's the online offline functionality.

Comment: you will have to duplicate your data on a local sqlite db and use it while offline mode. When online again synch/merge (on the case) the data with the server.

Comment: ... that doesn't really help anything. Try to find a solution yourself, and if you run into problems, than come back.

Comment: Thanks Adrian 
But can you please tell me how can i sync/merge using http services